# How to train a tokenizer on a big dataset?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

Based on [examples](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/flax/language-modeling), I am trying to train a tokenizer and a model for T5 for Persian.
I use Google Colab pro,
when I tried to run the following code:

```
import datasets

from t5_tokenizer_model import SentencePieceUnigramTokenizer


vocab_size = 32_000
input_sentence_size = None # change to 100_000 works

# Initialize a dataset
dataset = datasets.load_dataset("oscar", name="unshuffled_deduplicated_fa", split="train")

tokenizer = SentencePieceUnigramTokenizer(unk_token="<unk>", eos_token="</s>", pad_token="<pad>")

print("len dataset:", len(dataset))

# Build an iterator over this dataset
def batch_iterator(input_sentence_size=None):
    if input_sentence_size is None:
        input_sentence_size = len(dataset)
    batch_length = 100
    for i in range(0, input_sentence_size, batch_length):
        yield dataset[i: i + batch_length]["text"]


# Train tokenizer
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(
    iterator=batch_iterator(input_sentence_size=input_sentence_size),
    vocab_size=vocab_size,
    show_progress=True,
)

# Save files to disk
tokenizer.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/Pouramini/tokenizer.json")
```

It get stuck in `train_from_iterator` because the size of dataset is large (`input_sentence_size` is around 8M sentences)
How can I divide the dataset and run the code on each block and then merge them to a tokenizer output?

Comment: partitioning may apply.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using iterable datasets?

```
dataset = datasets.load_dataset("oscar", name="unshuffled_deduplicated_fa", split="train", streaming=True)

tokenizer = SentencePieceUnigramTokenizer(unk_token="<unk>", eos_token="</s>", pad_token="<pad>")

def batch_iterator(dataset):
    for i in dataset:
        yield i["text"]
```